# How do I make a different left accessory image for each annotation appear?

Tags: ios, ios5, uiimageview, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I'm stuck here and I thought I'd ask if anyone can help me with this as I'm getting ready to tear my hair out.

I'm using the following tutorial/guide below and got as far the end and it works great for the one image but what I want is to be able to set a different image/thumbnail for each individual annotation

[Tutorial/Guide](http://mayurbirari.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/how-to-access-mkmapkit-in-iphone/)

I've been trying to get this to work now for a while and I've just about had enough of looking at it. lol

I'm pretty new when it comes to xcode so that's why I'm struggling with it.

*From OP's "suggested edit to the answer":*

EDIT:

I Can't seem to get what you said to work and I'm stumped with it.

I've added a copy of my project at Dropbox below if it's possible for you to check it. It maybe abit of a mess at the moment as I've tried for ages and getting no where.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6ddhege240konzo/XrpuFYF5y5

I'm tempted just to figure out how to do the custom callout instead.

One thing I'm unsure about is delegates and how they really work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set the `leftCalloutAccessoryView` to a different image for each annotation.

The `leftCalloutAccessoryView` is a property of `MKAnnotationView` so you need to set it in the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method (which is where you create and return an `MKAnnotationView`).

The `viewForAnnotation` delegate method gets a reference to the annotation that you need to create a view for in the `annotation` parameter.

So based on some property of `annotation`, you set `leftCalloutAccessoryView` accordingly.

At the crudest level, you could set `leftCalloutAccessoryView` based on `annotation.title`.
For example: if title is "SFO" set image to "apple", if title is "ATL" set image to "peach", etc.

However, it's much better to create a separate property (in your annotation class that implements `MKAnnotation`) that clearly indicates what image to use for the annotation.  This property could be the `UIImage` itself, the name of the image, a number, etc.  -- whatever is best for your situation.

*When creating the annotation and before calling `addAnnotation`, you set this property of the annotation.*

Then in the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method, you set the `leftCalloutAccessoryView` based on the custom annotation property.

For example, assuming an `NSString` property named `imageName` was added to the annotation class:

```
MKAnnotationView *av = ... //or MKPinAnnotationView
//typical dequeue and alloc/init code here

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotationClass class]])
{
    //cast the annotation parameter to your custom class
    //so you can easily access the custom properties...
    MyAnnotationClass *myAnn = (MyAnnotationClass *)annotation;

    //create UIImage based on custom property of annotation...
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:myAnn.imageName];

    //create UIImageView to use for the leftCalloutAccessoryView...
    UIImageView *iv = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img] autorelease];
    //if using ARC, remove the autorelease above

    av.leftCalloutAccessoryView = iv;
}

return av;
```

Comment: Thanks Anna, Will give it a try in the morning.